# How to combine a String with a List in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to Python and i want to know how to combine a String with all the elements of a List and then save Output in a `.txt` File. But the window just open and close immediately because the code is wrong. This is my code:

```
List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

String = input("Please enter a name: ")
Output = String + List
print(Output)

f= open("Text.txt","w+")
f.write(Output + "\n")
f.close()
```

I am expecting to see this results:

```
Please enter a name: Username
Username1 Username2 Username3 Username4 Username5
```

And in the Text File like this:

```
Username1
Username2
Username3
Username4
Username5
```

How am i supposed to do this? If the question is not clear please let me know. My first language is not English so is hard for me to explain. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I suggest you read some of the PEP8 style guide in order to write more readable code.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reckon you can use a list comprehension:

```
List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

String = input("Please enter a name: ")

Output = [String + str(x) for x in List]

print(Output)
```

Output:

```
['Username1', 'Username2', 'Username3', 'Username4', 'Username5']
```

Comment: Then you have another for loop which then writes each of those entries into a new line on the text file

Comment: Yucky variable naming especially for someone who is just learning the language. I suggest an edit to name them something more reasonable.

Comment: @ChadVanDeHey I agree, but direct that to OP in his question.

Comment: @ChadVanDeHey Yeha, i know that but i change the name of the variables just to make this Question easier to understand because as i said its hard for me to explain because i don't speak English very well. In my real code i have used: Chars - List | Username - String | Password - Output | Which is think is good for me. Thanks for the suggestion anyway :)

Comment: @JacobG. Hm... I don't know if i am doing anything wrong but this is not working. I get an error after i type a name in the "String". Do you know what is going on?

Comment: @MarioAgolli What *error* are you getting?  It works perfectly fine on my end.

Comment: @JacobG. I get this for the 3rd command in Ben10 code: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. And when i run this in the Terminal after i give my input it just close and dont give me the output.

Comment: @MarioAgolli Why aren't you using the code posted above?  Can you post the line that you get the error on?

Comment: @JacobG. I am so sorry that i am taking your time but i have tried your code too and the Terminal just close after i give my input. I am not getting an error now for some reason but it just dont give me the output... When it give me the error before the terminal closed immediately so i culdnt copy it :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169468/discussion-between-jacob-g-and-mario-agolli).

Answer (score 1):

Following Jacob G. entry your code should look like this:

```
List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# input() only works for Python 3.x . Use raw_input() if using python 2.x
InputName = input("Please enter a name: ")
Usernames = [InputName + str(entry) for entry in List]
print(Usernames)

file= open("Text.txt","w+")
for username in Usernames:
   file.write(username)
file.close()
```

Comment: Aghh... I am sorry but both your code and Jacob G. code is not working. I don't know if i am doing anything wrong but after i give my input to the "InputName" the Terminal just close and the Text.txt file don't get created. I tried to type the code one by one in the Python IDLE and i get this error after i type the 2nd command: NameError: name 'username' is not defined.

Comment: And when i run the 3rd command i get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Ok for the first one - username cannot be found, have you put made sure that the line `file.write(username)` is in the for loop `for username in Usernames:`

Comment: @Ben10 It turns out OP was using Python 2.7 and had to use `raw_input` instead.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help again i really appreciate it but i have fixed the error now. The problem was that i was using Python 2.7 where you need to use raw_input and your code was for -V 3.x so i just installed the latest version of Python now and its working perfectly. Thanks a lot for helping me to get started :)